# Parse XML in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I trying parse xml from file. But result is empty

XML:

```
<custom-attributes>
    <custom-attribute attribute-id="color" xml:lang="x-default">BLACK</custom-attribute>
    <custom-attribute attribute-id="color_code" xml:lang="x default">1234</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>

<custom-attributes>
    <custom-attribute attribute-id="color_style" xml:lang="x-default">free</custom-attribute>
    <custom-attribute attribute-id="color" xml:lang="x-default">RED</custom-attribute>
    <custom-attribute attribute-id="color_code" xml:lang="x default">1234</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
```

How to parse in table?

```
Color    color_code
BLACK      1234
RED        1234
```

I tried this query:

```
 DECLARE @xml XML = '
<custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="color" xml:lang="x-default">BLACK</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="color_code" xml:lang="x default">1234</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>

<custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="color_style" xml:lang="x-default">free</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="color" xml:lang="x-default">RED</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="color_code" xml:lang="x default">1234</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>'

SELECT 
    Color =   x.t.value('(./custom-attribute)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/custom-attributes') AS x(t)
```

First column is correct. But second is not. How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `query`:

```
SELECT 
  Color=x.t.query('(./custom-attribute[@attribute-id="color"]/text())')
 ,Color_code=x.t.query('(./custom-attribute[@attribute-id="color_code"]/text())')
FROM @xml.nodes('/custom-attributes') AS x(t);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bcdfce46ceaf297b05d5352aa8a2606a)**

Answer (score 1):

You should try :

```
 Declare @fileData  XML 
             Select @fileData=BulkColumn from OpenRowSet(Bulk'PATH\FILENAME.xml',Single_blob) x;
             select 
                x.xData.value('custom-attribute[@attribute-id="color"][1]','nvarchar(max)') as color,
                x.xData.value('custom-attribute[@attribute-id="color_code"][1]','nvarchar(max)') as color_code,
                x.xData.value('custom-attribute[@attribute-id="color_style"][1]','nvarchar(max)')as color_style
             from @fileData.nodes('/custom-attributes') 
             x(xData);
```